# Funny colours in desktop after fresh installation of 14.04LTS

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, fonts

I have problem with fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04, I havent installed anything but this is what I saw http://postimg.org/image/btfnarkdn/. Then I installed Nvidia drivers but it is still same.

As you can see, in the top bar font is black and the bar itself is transparent, which i think shouldnt be. Also buttons in windows look really weird. Anyone to help me?

Comment: Try right-clicking on the desktop, or open the appearance Settings property page, and changing the Theme back and forth.  I've had messed up themes that get fixed this way.

Comment: Does it still happen if you create a new user account and login to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your system settings got that way, but it appears to me that this is a result of non-standard settings. In the past I have messed with appearance settings and it is definitely possible to changes the colors and the transparency of the top bar, as well as many other things.

One approach would be to got to Settings->Appearance and change the theme you are using.

Another would be to install compizconfig-settings-manager

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

and use the ccsm command to change the appearance of your desktop--but be careful to limiting changes to just colors, fonts, etc.

unity-tweak-tool

`sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`

may be easier and safer.